# *-algebra, isomorphic to a C*-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

A C-*-algebra A is *-isomorphic to a *-algebra B. 
Any examples when in this case B is not A C-*-algebra?

Comment: Is there already a norm on $B$? If not, take $A=B$ and put a norm on $B$ which is not a $C^*$ norm. Example: take $A=(\mathbb{C})$ with the usual Euclidean $|z|$, and $B=\mathbb{C}$ with $\|z\|=2|z|$.

Answer (score 5):

No, $B$ needs not be a $C^*$-algebra in general. Just take $A=B$ with a $C^*$ norm on one side and a non $C^*$-norm on the other side.

But note the following more interesting fact.
If $A$ and $B$ are $*$-isomorphic $C^*$-algebras, then the $*$-homomorphism is automatically isometric.

This follows from the fact that 
$$
\|x\|^2=\|x^*x\|=\rho(x^*x)
$$
where $\rho(x^*x)$ is the spectral radius of $x^*x$, which is algebraic and does not depend on the $C^*$-norm.

Comment: In other words: if there is a C\*-norm on a \*-algebra $A$ then it is unique. I think a simple and natural example would be the unitization $A_1 = A \rtimes \mathbb{C}$ of a non-unital C\*-algebra. One is tempted to put the norm $\lVert (a,\lambda)\rVert = \lVert a\rVert + \lvert \lambda\rvert$ or something similar on $A_1$ while the C\*-norm on $A_1$ is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: @Martin Yes, absolutely! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't well-defined. A precise question would be: If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, $B$ is a $*$-algebra and the underlying $*$-algebra of $A$ is isomorphic to $B$, does it follow that $B$ is the underlying $*$-algebra of a $C^*$-algebra? And is this $C^*$-algebra isomorphic to $A$?

The answer is yes. If $\phi : B \to A$ is a $*$-isomorphism, then $||-|| \circ \phi$ defines a norm on $B$, and it is easily checked that this defines a $C^*$-algebra structure on $B$. By construction $\phi$ is an isometric isomorphism of $C^*$-algebras.